Can I pass down sx props with MUI v6 and pigment-css?
I am currently migrating my team's Next.Js + MUI app to MUI v6.
While doing so I came across this error when trying to run the dev server:
⨯ unhandledRejection: SyntaxError: path/to/my/Component.tsx: @pigment-css/react: You can only use variables in the spread that are defined in the root scope of the file.
  59 |                     }
  60 |                 },
> 61 |                 ...sx
     |                 ^^^^^
  62 |             }),
  63 |         ...props,
  64 |         children: children

I am a bit stumped by the underlying message, and just want some confirmation: Is it not possible to pass down sx props to components in MUI v6 with pigment-css?
I can work around the underlying styling issue with CSS classes, but the sx prop was always the go-to solution for me in MUI v5. Has the paradigm shifted to more class-based styles with MUI v6?
Another thing I tried was merging the sx props with the styles more explicitly, via:
            sx={(theme) => {
                const baseStyles = {
                    // my styles
                };
                const completeStyles = sx
                    ? { ...baseStyles, ...sx }
                    : baseStyles;

                return completeStyles as SystemStyleObject;
            }}

But to no avail, as I was met with yet another error:
SyntaxError: path/to/my/Component.tsx: @pigment-css/react: sx prop only supports arrow functions directly returning an object, for example () => ({color: 'red'}). You can accept theme object in the params if required.
  22 |     ]);
  23 |     return /*#__PURE__*/ _jsxDEV(Box, {
> 24 |         sx: (theme)=>{
     |                      ^
  25 |             const baseStyles = {

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
